# Embed GitHub repository overview and stats

Tags: github

Is there a way to embed a GitHub repo overview (showing its stats, creator and description, etc.) into a webpage?

In Slack, if you paste a GitHub repo URL, it will show the repo description and user thumbnail.

[image: slack onebox of github repo]

I'm wondering if there something like this:

```
<>some html that contains GitHub repo url</>
<script src="some js it provides"></script>
```

and it could show me the same thing on a webpage.

There's [a way to embed GitHub Gists](https://github.com/blog/122-embedded-gists), but is there one for GitHub repos?

Comment: Slack probably use the Github API. https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get

Comment: @ceejayoz I know. If there's no such thing I would probably write my own but if there is, I'll just use it.

Comment: Changed it slightly away from asking a service (which is out of scope and would be closed) to something asking foremost if it's even possible

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise OK, didn't know there's a way to embed gist.

Comment: Out of the box, no. But some sites would embed GitHub repo info: https://meta.discourse.org/t/what-is-a-onebox/4546

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I found this

https://github.com/lepture/github-cards

It's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way.
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/

Make a get request with curl to the GitHub API and the API will return relevant data in a JSON array.

Comment: I'm aware of this, that's not what I exactly need.

Comment: I understand this is not completely what you need. What you are asking cannot be done with just JavaScript and HTML. You will need to connect to the GitHub API and then make a curl request. Once you make the curl request you can format the JSON data with JavaScript in an HTML page.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sure. In fact I'm not asking how to do this, but is it already done.